# email activation link not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration and login system which works fine... up to a point. After a user registers, an email is sent with an activation code. The expected behaviour is that on clicking the email activation link the registered but unverified 'status' column in my database will be reset from default integer value of 0 to 1. However, the 'status' is updated simply on sending the email, without the user having to click the activation link!

I have searched the Stack Overflow site, viewed tutorials, and tried many permutations on the code without success.

```
    if (isset($_GET['email']) AND isset ($_GET['vkey'])){

    if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT email, vkey FROM members WHERE email = ? AND vkey = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['email'], $_GET['vkey']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows ==1) {


    if ($stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE members SET status = 1 WHERE email = ? AND vkey = ?')) {
    // Set status to 1
    //$status = 1;
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['email'], $_GET['vkey']);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Your account is now activated. You can now login.<br><a href="login.php">Login</a>';
    }
    } else {
        echo 'Your account is already activated or doesn\'t exist!';
    }
}
```

I expect the database 'status' column to be updated only if the user clicks the verification link in the email, but it updates immediately the email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the API you're sending the email from is not clicking the link inside the email. Some email providers do that.

You can check by logging the request and checking if it's called before you click the link.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know how to log and check the request. Can you advise on that.

Comment: You can write to a file and then append to it every time with the timestamp and check it when you need to read the logs.